# hardware environment for compilation performance

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, hardware

This is a rather general question ..

What hardware setup is best for large C/C++ compile jobs, like a Linux kernel or Applications ?

I remember reading a post by Joel Spolsky on experiments with solid state disks and stuff like that.

Do I have to have rather more CPU power or more RAM or a fast harddisk IO solution like solid state ? Would it for example be convenient to have a 'normal' harddisk for the standard system and then use a solid state for the compilation ? Or can I just buy lots of RAM ? And how important is the CPU, or is it just sitting around most of the compile time ?

Probably it's a stupid question, but I dont have a lot of experience on that field, thanks for answers.

**Here's some info on the SSD issue**

- [Linus Torvalds on the topic](http://torvalds-family.blogspot.com/2008/10/so-i-got-one-of-new-intel-ssds.html)
- [How to get the most out of it (Standard settings are sort of slowing it down)](http://blogs.zdnet.com/perlow/?p=9190)
- [Interesting article on Coding Horror about it and with a tip for a payable Chipset](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001304.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need enough of everything. CPU is very important, and compiles can easily be parallelised (with `make -j`), so you want as many CPU cores as possible. Then, RAM is probably just as important, since it provides more 'working space' for the compiler **and** allows to your IO to be buffered. Finally, of course drive speed is probably the least important of the three - kernel code is big, but not **that** big.

Comment: Talking about memory, that would most likely imply that I have to have  a fast connection between CPU and RAM, I used a laptop computer most of the time in recent years, so I'm not really up to date .. Can I get away with a standard consumer mainboard ?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not a stupid question, getting the build-test environment tuned correctly will make a lot of headaches go away.

Hard disk performance would probably top the list. I'd stay well away from the solid state drive as they're only rated for a large-but-limited number of write operations and make-clean-build cycles will hammer it.

More importantly, can you take advantage of a parallel or shared build environment - from memory ClearCase and Perforce had mechanisms to handle shared builds. Unless you have a parallelising build system, having multiple CPUs will be fairly pointless

Last but not least, I would doubt that the build time would be the limiting factor - more likely you should focus on the needs of your test system. Before you look at the actual metal though, try to design a build-test system that's appropriate to how you'll actually be working - how often are your builds, how many people are involved, how big is your test system ....

Comment: SSD lifespan is now a non-issue. I used to worry about that, too, but modern SSDs have a per-cell lifetime of about a million writes. You could take a current SSD with a typical size, write speed, and wear-levelling controller, and do continuous writes 24x7 for years without a problem.

Build time is a limiting factor for a lot of people. I work on a code base of about 20 million lines of C, and often have to rebuild it from scratch, sometimes several times a day.

Both jam (from Perforce) and gnu make support parallel builds.

I'm analyzing all this stuff on my blog.